# Git clone fail due to repository not recognized

Tags: git

I was told that I could git clone a document using the following command (with some words changed for privacy, so it's not a real repository, but the format is unchanged):

```
git clone docs@docs.company.org/sub-dir/project_name_4
```

I am getting the error message telling me that the repository doesn't exist.

Obviously it's possible that the repository really doesn't exist - meaning that I was given the wrong path for the repository. But before I go back to the person who gave me the link, I wanted to check that there isn't anything dumb I'm doing wrong. Does this look like the correct format for example? Am I missing any commands?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` before `git clone` (`GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone ....`) for more debug information regarding the network request(s).

`docs@docs.company` means that you are trying to clone over ssh as the user *docs* against the host *docs.company.org*. You should need a `:` in there, as in `....company.org:/sub-dir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the url is wrong, or you don't have the permission to access it.

I can't be certain, but you probably meant `git clone docs@docs.company.org:sub-dir/project_name_4` (with `:` instead of `/` to separate the host and the path)

Comment: Yes, it was just that / should have been :   thank you!